Problem with running node socket.io server on azure web app
I have an app with a simple socket io server running on port 8080.
const io = new Server(socketServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: false,
  },
  transports: ["polling", "websocket"],
  pingTimeout: 5000,
  pingInterval: 5000,
});

The app is deployed to Azure Web App, and I deployed it to Linux 20 LTS (B1 plan). Since it's Linux-based, web socket support is enabled by default.
I run my server on port 8080, so I also pass the WEBSITES_PORT=8080 in my config. But what I can see in my log stream is weird - there are logs that the app is running, but it's like it's not available anyway, so I'm not sure if that settings are correct. Below is the log, I could see a message from the socket server that started, but then it all stopeed (I replaced app name):
2024-12-13T13:31:03  Startup Request, url: /webssh/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=PF0DioW&sid=U74M1zL11K-SaBJHAAAA, method: POST, type: request, pid: 87,1,5, ScmType: None/home/LogFiles/2024_12_13_lw0sdlwk0002AT_default_docker.log  (https://MYAPP-chat.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_12_13_lw0sdlwk0002AT_default_docker.log)
2024-12-13T14:04:23.950468637Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2024-12-13T14:04:23.950471337Z
2024-12-13T14:04:23.950473737Z export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
2024-12-13T14:04:23.950476437Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2024-12-13T14:04:23.950479037Z      export PORT=8080
2024-12-13T14:04:23.950481837Z fi
2024-12-13T14:04:23.950484237Z
2024-12-13T14:04:23.950486537Z PATH="$PATH:/home/site/wwwroot" node ./server.js
############ WebSocket server for CHAT is running on port 8080 - this comes from the running server ##############
2024-12-13T14:04:29.440177474Z WebSocket server for CHAT is running on port 8080/home/LogFiles/2024_12_13_lw0sdlwk0002AT_default_scm_docker.log  (https://MYAPP-chat.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_12_13_lw0sdlwk0002AT_default_scm_docker.log)
2024-12-13T14:00:13.4133537Z Fri Dec 13 14:00:13 UTC 2024 running .net core
2024-12-13T14:00:15.3614556Z Startup : 02.00.15.293858
2024-12-13T14:00:15.3889868Z Configure Services : 02.00.15.388858
2024-12-13T14:00:16.8018705Z Configure : 02.00.16.801752
2024-12-13T14:00:17.5251302Z Setting Up Routes : 02.00.17.525013
2024-12-13T14:00:18.1064158Z Exiting Configure : 02.00.18.106309
2024-12-13T14:00:18.4782376Z Hosting environment: Production
2024-12-13T14:00:18.4788463Z Content root path: /opt/Kudu
2024-12-13T14:00:18.4795422Z Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8181
2024-12-13T14:00:18.4798312Z Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down./home/LogFiles/2024_12_13_lw0sdlwk0002AT_docker.log  (https://MYAPP-chat.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_12_13_lw0sdlwk0002AT_docker.log)
2024-12-13T14:04:14.1309786Z Container is terminated. Total time elapsed: 939 ms.
2024-12-13T14:04:14.1313689Z Site container: MYAPP-chat terminated during site startup.
2024-12-13T14:04:14.8327528Z Site: MYAPP-chat stopped.
2024-12-13T14:04:17.534Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2024-12-13T14:04:17.536Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8080 --name MYAPP-chat_0_cd509984 -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=true -e WEBSITES_PORT=8080 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=MYAPP-chat -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=MYAPP-chat.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=123 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/node:20-lts_20240819.2.tuxprod REDACTED
2024-12-13T14:04:19.678Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container MYAPP-chat_0_cd509984 for site MYAPP-chat
2024-12-13T14:07:36.019Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container MYAPP-chat_0_cd509984. Elapsed time = 196.3403018 sec
2024-12-13T14:08:37.931Z ERROR - Container MYAPP-chat_0_cd509984 for site MYAPP-chat did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 258.2538017 sec
2024-12-13T14:08:37.944Z ERROR - Container MYAPP-chat_0_cd509984 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2024-12-13T14:08:37.987Z INFO  - Stopping site MYAPP-chat because it failed during startup.Ending Log Tail of existing logs ---Starting Live Log Stream ---
2024-12-13T14:10:08  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2024-12-13T14:11:08  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2024-12-13T14:12:08  No new trace in the past 3 min(s).
2024-12-13T14:13:08  No new trace in the past 4 min(s).
2024-12-13T14:14:08  No new trace in the past 5 min(s).
2024-12-13T14:15:08  No new trace in the past 6 min(s).

Of course, when connecting with the client I get timeout error.

@akkonard Is this a pure Node.js app? If so, how are you defining the port in your code?

I've found the solution, so posting the answer. But to answer your question - I had WEBSITES_PORT set to the port the app used. The reason for failure is explained in the response.

It took me a while, but the reason I disabled the container after some time was that the health check failed. It failed because there was no way to check it on the web socket server. I read this page in the Azure documentation and added an express app with a health check endpoint. It works like a charm.

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/health", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("OK"));

const httpServer = createServer(app);

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  // ...
});

This way httpServer can handle both HTTP and WEBSOCKET protocols.
